# Clear 301-redirect cache in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Is it possible to clear ***only* 301-redirects** from Firefox's cache? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't do the job since you just reload the target without caching but do not clear the cached redirect.

An option to disable caching of those redirects completely would be fine, too - but some way (possibly through an extension) to remove those cached redirects would be better.

Note: I'm not looking for answers that disable all caching (including CSS, JS, etc.)

Comment: Use 302 or 307 if you want to redirect temporarily... 301 is for permanent redirection...

Comment: I know that. But sometimes you forget to change that or your framework uses one (for example, Flask does so when redirecting from `/foo` to `/foo/`)

Comment: Hmm most of the frameworks turn off cache by debug mode, or you can turn it off manually if you add `no-cache, no-store` headers. That will prevent cache by `301 header`s too, if I am right. If it was cached recently, you can clear the recent cache by `history/clear recent history`. If it was not recent, you can find the site in the history, click on it with the right button and choose `delete this page` or `forget about this site`. Theoretically all of these are working, in practice I never used them to remove a redirection from the cache...

Comment: More answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980192

Comment: FYI - 302 gets cached as well

Comment: "This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field." - so unlike 301 it shouldn't be cached all the time

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox#1287318) always works for me, as long as you know the exact URL that you need to drop (read the comment too!)

Comment: @inf3rno How can I do these things if I don't run the website I'm having problems with?

Comment: @Stewart You can't.

Answer (score 390):

Locate the site you are redirected from in the History sidebar. Right-click it and select "Forget about this site".

No addons required!

P.S. I'm pretty sure this didn't work in the past, but nowadays following the redirect and then clearing the cache for past hour will actually remove the cached redirect.

P.S. The current [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796598/448474) is to use "Web Developer Tools" (Ctrl+Alt+I), click "Network" and click "Disable cache". Load the original URL. Enable the cache again. The page is refreshed in the cache and the original URL is accessible also from other tabs now.

Comment: Didn't work for me, too.

Comment: Works for me too. Make sure you delete the history entry of the site you're being redirected *from*, not the site you're redirected *to*.

Comment: Works for Desktop, would like to do the same for Android.

Comment: Worked for me without needing to delete the history of the entire sire being redirected from.

Comment: Doesn't work on latest Firefox (version 40)

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox 41. But note: "Forget about this site" will forget the cached pages, URL history (needed for auto-completion) and even saved passwords for the *whole domain*. It says "site", not "page", and this feature seems intended to protect your surf history privacy. It might not be what you want here, so be careful.

Comment: Works in Firefox 50. The end of many hours of frustration.

Comment: I have disabled history in Firefox. So the history list is empty and I can't clear it. :(

Comment: click on the right side (hamburger ) menu, then `history`, `clear recent history`, select `Today` and check only the `Cache`. Click `Clear now` button. That worked for me. Firefox V - 55.0.3

Comment: BEWARE! Based on my experience with FF so far (from version 40-something up to the nightly build from Apr. 13), this clears ALL entries (for ALL domains) in the browser *cache* (except for a very few particular websites, whose behaviour I have yet to investigate), not just the site that you are trying to forget!

Comment: Thank you very much! That just worked. (I had accidentally set a 301 redirect for the wildcard subdomain to www.…, which broke all subdomains managed at the secondary DNS … )

Comment: This will also clear cookies, as well as other things.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: This doesn't work if the redirect is to another domain. In that case there is no history entry for the domain you were redirected _from_, so there is nothing to click.

Comment: In Firefox 75, it says "Forget this page", and it seems the cookies are still safe after that.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski There is if one has browsed the site before it got redirected.  In my case, my Internet connection dropped and I was redirected to a diagnostic page, but it would appear that this is wrongly using a 301 code and so I was stuck with this redirect.  Still, there is a problem with this 'solution' in that it erases _everything_ about the site, including cookies and saved logins.

Comment: This is the right answer, should be accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 40):

The quickest way to remove the cache in Firefox, which includes 301 redirects, is the following:

- Press **CTRL + SHIFT + Delete**
- Change the time range, if needed
- Click on *Details* and uncheck everything other than "*cache*"

Comment: This actually works fine, no need to downvote.

Comment: This is somehow overkill since it deletes at least the last our of activity, but may be useful.

Comment: Better to loose the last hour than the whole history, saved passwords etc... Thanks

Comment: Not working in Firefox 66

Comment: @dario True, but it may be the case that the redirect was cached a long time ago.  As I look now (FF 101.0.1), the options provided are "Last hour", "Last two hours", "Last four hours", "Today" and "Everything", which is very restrictive.  So even if it was only yesterday, unless you're still within four hours of the caching event then you're stuck with clearing the entire history.

Comment: On macOS, the combination is Command + Shift + Delete.

Comment: This actually helped me, while "Forget About This Site" did not help me with 301 redirects. I know it does not remove ONLY the redirects, as OP wanted, but I badly needed to remove them, so I cleared both histories and cache (without cookies and logins) and it helped.

Answer (score 32):

Here is the simple solution for this in Firefox:

> Hamburger menu -> Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Clear Data (under Cookies and Site Data)

Make sure "Cached Web Content" is checked. You probably want to uncheck "Cookies and Site Data". And then click "Clear", and it's done.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Unlike my solution, this works even if your only visit to the site is a redirect to an error page, because those don't appear in the history and you have nothing to click "Forget about this site" on.

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that it doesn't clear **only 301-redirect** as the OP would like.

Comment: When the @RomanSt fails, this helps. +1

Answer (score 27):

The only solution I've found so far - short of clearing the whole cache - is the "Disable entire cache" toggle in [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/). Once disabled you hard reload the page and you get the new version (remember to uncheck the toggle after you're done).

Comment: I see a "Disable DNS cache" option, and that seems to do what I want. Very annoying this caching! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Additionally to "Disable entire cache" I had to select "Check For Newer Version Of Page Every Time" for the redirect cache to be forgotten. This is the only solution that worked for me on Firefox 35.0.1.

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me FF 59.0 - resending the request did not clear it & clearing more caches was not an option

Comment: Somewhat obvious, but this checkbox is in the 'network' tab in the developer toolbar.  It's now just called 'disable cache'.  I like this because it doesn't wipe all info about the site from the cache.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution that worked for me. Deleting from history didn't work.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution is;

- Open the Developer toolbar on the Network tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)
- Ensure the "All" or "HTML" filter is enabled on the bottom row
- Navigate to the URL you're receiving a cached redirect on, as usual
- Notice the first HTML request will show a 301 in the Network list
- Right-click that row, choose "Edit and Resend"
- A pane will display on the right, allowing you to edit the HTTP request. Just click "Send"
- A new HTML request will show in the Network list, this time (hopefully!) returning a 200
- Navigate to the URL again, it should work as expected

Comment: Thanks, this is a good scalpel-y way that works for pages that return an error (and thus don't show in history).

Comment: This answer looks complicated, but to me it is the only one that actually answer the OP's question: remove only the 301-redirect cache.

Comment: This does not work with FF 59.0.1, or at least with some requests. Clicking "Send" does nothing. Not sure whether https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1151932 is related, but it discusses similar symptoms.

Comment: This is actually the only one that worked for me though the second to last option seems to hang on luck. I spent several hours on this annoying issue getting redirect loops in outlook. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work in FF 73.0 (Linux). The resent request returns 200, however browsing to the URL still redirects :(

Comment: This is the best approach among all answers. Nevertheless still like @Beli: I may force the resending, I then get a 200, but when browsing the URL from the nav bar, it uses the cache again giving a 301 instead of having cached that now it is a 200. Upvoted to boost this answer up. But guys, we still need a way to tell FF "and this new request is the valid one, forget about that cache". Isn't there any list of "cached responses" to selectivelly tell "foget about this one"?

Comment: After my comment 1 hour ago... Built on top of this answer, I create this other answer https://superuser.com/a/1734256/324451

Answer (score 8):

Late answer. With Firefox 50.

1. Open up `Web Developer` in Firefox (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Open up `Toolbox Options` (Gear/Cog shape icon on top of `Web Developer` window)
3. Under `Advanced Settings`, check the box `Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)`.

With `Web Developer` windows opened, redirect cache will be refreshed.

Comment: I'm quite sure this disables the whole cache altogether, making reloads of a large application with lots of JS/CSS files - even when running locally - awfully slow.

Comment: It's a solution to clear your redirect cache frustration ( almost no way good way to clear it, i disabled history on my browser, other answers above don't solve my problem :( ). Then either close the Web Developer (F12) or uncheck the options then you can continue on development. :)

Comment: When the checkbox is checked, it doesn't redirect, as expected. However, as soon as I uncheck the checkbox, the redirect returns. It looks like this does not clear the cache.

Comment: For Firefox 75, it works best of all the answers. It suffices to hit the url only once, then you re-enable checkbox `Disable HTTP Cache` and the cached redirect is cleared forever. If it doesn't work for you, use the Network tab to look at Response Header named `Location`, maybe the 301 redirect is still served from the site and not from the cache.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are on windows, and the url is not shown in the browser history**

Use a search tool like [wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) or the option "Find in files..." in Notepad++ to search for files under this path:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\...
```

Search for files that contains both the exact text: `Moved Permanently`, and the URL that are redirecting.

The search might take a minute, and might return more than one file.

Then simply delete the file(s) found, and restart Firefox.

Comment: Which is even more of a hassle than just clearing the cache considering your solutions needs a browser restart...

Comment: Your question was: "_Is it possible to clear **only** 301-redirects from Firefox's cache?_" ...

Answer (score 2):

You can clear cached redirects as a part of browsing history, selecting a time range. For the recent Firefox Quantum 57.0.3, here's how to do it:

1. Click the hamburger menu ***or*** the library button next to the search bar.
2. Click 'History'.
3. Click 'Clear Recent History...'.
4. Expand 'Details' clicking a small button next to the label.
5. **Uncheck** all but 'Cache'. *Optionally:* select the preferred 'Time range to clear'.
6. Click 'Clear Now'.

For earlier versions of Firefox, see [@mihkov](https://superuser.com/users/728187/mihkov)'s [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox#comment1832579_661767) on the question.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! It's good to link to the comment you used for reference, but it's even better to add the context in the answer itself, to make the answer self-contained. That way, someone looking at your answer does not have to read the comment thread first.

Answer (score 1):

## Solved!

Tested with Firefox `v103.0`

After liking very much the answer from @NoChecksum here https://superuser.com/a/998118/324451 I found that after resending the request it gave a `200` "locally in the inspector" but still did not clear the cached `301`. And when loading via URL again, the cache was used again.

## Clue = TL;DR

In `Inspector | Network` there's the option `Disable cache`.

1. Check.
2. Load.
3. Uncheck.
4. Load again.

Voilà the `301` has gone.

## How to reproduce

I'm sharing here the full process to reproduce "force FF to cache the 301" and then "force FF to forget the 301". Here's how I did it in **8 steps:**

1. I installed a docker with a wordpress in port 80 in localhost. There are a myriad ways to enable/disable `301` and `200` back and forth, but running a predefined docker image is a split-second. Any other way would work too. After lanching the docker I just set the data for my DB connection and continued until I had something running. I randomly called the site `Tiendas` during the installation process.

[image: Running a wordpress]

2. I then entered the database and told the wordpress it was installed in a random port `7901` (where there's nobody listening). This was to "force" the `301 Redirect` and force Firefox to cache it. going to nowhere.

[image: In HeidiSql I tuned the fort to force a 301 redirect]

3. I went to my firefox and loaded `127.0.0.1` and the apache responded `301 Redirect` by transferring `303 bytes`. This redirection told Firefox to go to `127.0.0.1:7901`, which yielded in a second request and finally rendering `Unable to connect`.

[image: I forced Firefox to cache the 301 redirect]

4. I tested Firefox was using the cache. Loaded `127.0.0.1` in the URL but as we can see in the inspector, it did not send a request. It was using the cache so the URL ends up being `127.0.0.1:7901` giving `Unable to connect`. So we checked the cache "is in place".

[image: Testing the 301 was cached]

5. Now I set back the apache to answer a 200 via telling the wordpress it's no longer in `127.0.0.1:7901` but in `127.0.0.1`, so a request to `127.0.0.1` should answer the contet of the home page with a `200 ok`. I set it touching the database directly:

[image: Resetting the wordpress to the proper place]

6. Now it comes the fancy part. I set again `127.0.0.1` in the URL. But **(and this is the original problem in this question)** Firefox kept insisting in using the cache. Of curse Firefox did not know that things in the backend changed. So we ended up again (incorrectly this time) into `127.0.0.1:7901` with a `Unable to connect` while there's a server behind willing to serve us.

[image: Firefox still used the cache even if in the server there's somebody desiring to give us a 200 okey]

7. Now it comes the magic: In the `Inspector | Network` enable the `Disable Cache` option and load `127.0.0.1`. We can see it loads the page again (this time `10.34 KB transferred` and also it loads all the contents (css, js, etc.). Voilà! We now have in the URL the desired `127.0.0.1`. No redirects, no caches, nothing. All **forced** to be loaded. We can see the `Tiendas` site.

[image: The cache is forced to be ignored]

8. The time to see the truth... will it work? I unchecked the `Disable Cache` option to enable caching. Then loaded `127.0.0.1` again. I can see that now FireFox is loading cached what it can (for example the js, ico, etc.) and it is **not using** the **old** cached `301`. Just this `301` has been completely forgotten and not redirected to `127.0.0.1:7901` anymore.

[image: It works]

Hope it helps!