# Fritzbox blacklist not working for redirected URL in Firefox

Tags: blacklist, fritzbox

After setting up a blacklist in Fritzbox web interface, the unwanted sites are blocked nicely. However, a site (actually: superuser with wrong top level domain) that previously redirected to another site escapes blocking and still redirects to a comercial site (jacobi.de) in firefox (but not in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Firefox caches redirections (see also helpful answers from [RomanSt](https://superuser.com/a/661767/225142) and [user1983017](https://superuser.com/a/688240/225142)) and thus circumvents blocking *before* the router-based blacklist can be used. Two solutions:

- search for "blocked" site (*from* where redirection starts, not the destination site), right click, "forget about this site".
- Go to "Options", "Cookies and Site Data", "Clear data", check cache (not necessarily cookies) and delete.

(both tested on Win 10 + Firefox 72.0.1)