# In Firefox, stop autocomplete when entering URL

Tags: firefox, url, autocomplete

I have been doing some local web development and have been using the web address http://127.0.0.1:8000 extensively. But for the life of me, when I enter this address into the URL bar, I can no longer go to that site as Firefox is automatically sending me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/ which was a site I was extensively using previously.

I have tried deleting all history of http://127.0.0.1. I have tried unchecking "Browsing History" from the Settings section "Address Bar — Firefox Suggest". I have tried going into "about.config" and setting "browser.urlbar.autofill" to False. It still does the redirect. I should note that in a private window it does not do that, making me think it has something to do with the history. But I have tried deleting it and even disabled the autocomplete feature, and it still happens. Given all the steps I've tried, does anyone know why?

Lastly, I want to note I saw [Remove suggestion from Firefox autocomplete in URL input field](https://superuser.com/questions/1755870/remove-suggestion-from-firefox-autocomplete-in-url-input-field) and while the question is almost exact as
mine, none of the solutions worked for me. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider

1. You had a previous redirect from `:8000` to `:8000/catalog` and the browser remembers it.  To fix this, clear the browser cache.
2. The browser is doing an autofill.  Just move the cursor past the 8000 and press <kbd>del</kbd> to clear the rest of the line (ie catalog).
3. I am developing too, so I find it easier to have a simple webpage on my localhost that has all the links that I want to test again and again.  You could set one up too.  This includes links to Google, Bing and Yandex too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought clearing browser history also implicitly cleared the cache. But specifically removing the entire cache from Firefox worked! And, yes, I did have a previous redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Firefox 113, released in May 2023, you can:

- start typing the URL
- click the meatball menu (horizontal triple dot) icon on the right of the suggestion:

[image: Triple dot icon]

- choose `Remove from history`

See [docs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions) for more info.

That's if you're asking about autocomplete in fact, rather than just a cached redirect, which you seem to be doing. For that, there are many detailed answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox), for instance.