# cache can't be cleared for a specific site in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

My firefox browser just can't clear out the cache of a specific site: http://www.foundationdrillandtool.com/, the site shows no menu in my Firefox but OK in other browsers and also OK for other users using Firefox. I cleared the cache by going to Tools/Options/Advanced/Network/Cached Web Content

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you believe that your cache is not being cleared?

> the site shows no menu in my Firefox but OK in other browsers

Maybe this is due to a bug in the website causing it to fail loading the menu on Firefox. In which case its no a problem you can fix at your end (except for switching to a browser that works), you need to inform the webmaster of the website to fix it.

Comment: The site was created by myself but I have no idea why it suddenly happened, I have shut down the site for now and hopefully get some help from the vendor of the template I am using.

Comment: ok, but again there is no evidence to support that the fault is with the browser cache. It could also be a plugin (ad block?) you have loaded into firefox that interferes with the menu. Try running firefox disabling all plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows:

c:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\SOMERANDOMSTUFF\Cache

Just trash the contents of that directory while Firefox isn't running.