# How do I purge the cache of a given URL?

Tags: firefox

It seem that there is no way to purge or clear out the cache of a given website or URL in Firefox. Is this true? I am using version 18.0.2 at the moment.

I have found this old question:
[How can I clear a single site from the cache in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox)

But the the force-refresh trick (Ctrl+F5) will not sufice and the Firefox add-on that's mentioned is not supported by version 18.0.2 of Firefox.

So what can I do? Do I really need to clear the cache for EVERYTHING just to get to this single website that is bothering me? Is this really necessary?...

What about Internet Explorer? Is it possible to do this in IE?

Comment: The "website" in question is an internal website, a web interface in my network to be specific. That's why I specifically asked for a way to purge the cache of a given URL, rather than a "website". But the same thing applies to other URLs or websites as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with losing all information about that site (cookies, form info, passwords, history, etc.) then:

1. Open a new tab and go to `about:permissions`.
2. Search for the site in question and select it.
3. Click on the "Forget about this site" button in the top right hand corner.

Alternatively, you can use the history panel (Ctrl+H on Windows) to search for the site, right-click on it and click on "Forget about this site". It does the same action, but it's faster to access.

NOTE: I could not actually find the official documentation detailing that this clears the cache, but I found other sources stating that it does and tried it out myself (loaded a site, refreshed with dev tools open to ensure that files were stored in the cache (got a not modified 304 response), "forgot" about the site, reloaded site to see that the resources had to be redownloaded).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out. I will not mark it as a solution until I know for sure it works. Until then, I would appreciate other suggestions as well. And what about IE? Does anyone know how to do the same in this browser? Again, thanks for this tip!

Comment: I tested this approach right now in Firefox 18.0.2. It works perfectly, unwanted cached redirect has been deleted. +1
(I use http-equiv="refresh" to redirect, and when I change the destination url, Firefox keeps showing the old page until I let it forget the site this way.)