# How can I clear the url cache in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox on Windows 10.  ON one PC I have it always run in private mode.  On another, I periodically clear the history.  In either case, when I type in the url box, it still has all the history of urls I have typed before.  This is persistent across sessions and reboots.

This does not make it private at all.  I am using the following settings for **Clearing History**

- Browsing and Download History
- Form and Search History
- Cache
- Flash Cookies
- DownThemAll History and Queue

I am not clearing

- Active Logins
- Cookies (I do this manually)
- Site Preferences
- Offline Web Site Data

How can I clear this url cache ?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [How can I clear a single site from the cache in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox).  Because this history is wiped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the urls come from your bookmarks and not from the history (which is wiped)?

Comment: I just tested it and you are correct.